# what's the correct way to pipe input to a program's internal command line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, sqoop2

I'm trying to automate the installation of `Sqoop 2`. Suppose the `sqoop-server` is installed in the ip address `1.2.3.4`.
On the `sqoop-client` I want to set that server's ip. Manually, to do so, I would:

```
sqoop2
sqoop:000> set server --host 1.2.3.4
```

how could I accomplish that using shell's `pipe` and `echo`? I've tried

```
set server --host 1.2.3.4 | sqoop2
```

but it didn't quite work.

Comment: The `set` command set command line arguments `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` for the shell on the LHS of the pipeline, which then exited without providing any input to `sqoop2`.  That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Many interactive programs read from *stdin*. Assuming this is the case for `sqoop2` you might use a pipe as you suggested. But you just forget to use the `echo` command:

```
echo set server --host 1.2.3.4 | sqoop2
```

The code above set the output of `echo` as the input of `sqoop2`.
An other option is to use a [*here string*](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)

```
sqoop2 <<< "set server --host 1.2.3.4"
```

A third option is to use a [*here doc*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Very useful if you have to send multiple commands:

```
sqoop2 << 'EOF'
set server --host 1.2.3.4
EOF
```

(in the above, you might issue as many command as you want before the *EOF* marker that ends the *heredoc* then the shell will send all the commands to the programs `sqoop2` as its standard input)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`expect(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to script interactive programs.